# Passing only some touch events from one view to another view

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I am trying to implement an image view that can be zoomed and also have text scrolled over the top. In my view controller I have a scroll view containing the image view and set to zoom with no issues.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!


    //First try getting the image setup correctly

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupImageView()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func setupImageView() {

        scrollView.contentSize = imageView.bounds.size
        scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.5
        scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 2.0

    }

    func viewForZoomingInScrollView(scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return imageView
    }


    func scrollViewDidZoom(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        let imageViewSize = imageView.frame.size
        let scrollViewSize = scrollView.bounds.size

        let verticalPadding = imageViewSize.height < scrollViewSize.height ? (scrollViewSize.height - imageViewSize.height) / 2 : 0
        let horizontalPadding = imageViewSize.width < scrollViewSize.width ? (scrollViewSize.width - imageViewSize.width) / 2 : 0

        scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: verticalPadding, left: horizontalPadding, bottom: verticalPadding, right: horizontalPadding)
    }


}
```

Now I want to place another scroll view on top so text labels can be scrolled if dragged on, but the image can still be pinched and zoomed when it is touched on. I placed another scroll view on top of the image one (not inside) and then placed a content view and `UILabel` inside that, as I usually do when setting up scroll views in the IB. The text of course scrolls however the image won't pinch and zoom unless I subclass both the content view and top scrollview with:

```
override func pointInside(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
        for subview in subviews as [UIView] {
            if !subview.hidden && subview.alpha > 0 && subview.userInteractionEnabled && subview.pointInside(convertPoint(point, toView: subview), withEvent: event) {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }
```

[image]

This passes the touches to the scrollview below. However now I can't scroll the text! Is there any way to set this up so the `UILabel` with the test isn't passing the touches and can scroll but outside does pass and allows the image to zoom? Any pointers on this would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

`ScrollView` hacking is not always the most intuitive process. But in this case, why not let your `UIViewController` implement the `UIScrollViewDelegate` protocol and use the built in `zoomFeature` in `UIScrollview`?

Set `minimumZoomScale` and the `maximumZoomScale` for the `UIScrollView`
and make your `scrollViewDelegate` implement the following function and return the `imageView` you wish to `zoom`:

```
func viewForZooming(in: UIScrollView)
```

API Reference - [UIScrollView](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiscrollview)
- [UIScrollViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiscrollviewdelegate)

Comment: I'm using built in zoom on the first scrollview for the image. There is a second scroll view on top of the image for the text I want to scroll. I want to pass the touches so it can zoom the scrollview underneath but not pass them when the text is touched on, so the text can scroll.